# Fancy indexing of numpy recarray lost reference after assignment

Tags: python, list, numpy, indexing, recarray

I found a strange situation with my code and the issue is shown in the code bellow

```
import numpy as np

dt = dict(names = ['n1','n2'], formats = ['a8','int'])
reca = np.recarray((10,), dtype = dt)
reca['n1'] = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','e','f','g']
reca['n2'] = range(10)

sreca = reca[::2]
print sreca[0] in reca

sreca[0]['n2'] = 12
print sreca[0] in reca

ireca = reca[[1,3,5,7]]
print ireca[0] in reca

ireca[0]['n2'] = 7
print ireca[0] in reca
```

The output is:

```
True
True
True
False
```

To my understand, either `sreca` or `ireca` should keep a reference of `reca` unless i assign a new value to them directly, but `ireca` lost its reference after the assignment. I don't know if this is expected or not.

Could any one advice me how to avoid this?

BTW, I found that a small change of the code (`reca['n1'] = ['a']*10` for example) will give me all `True` in this sample, this really make me confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using fancy indexing in a `recarray` will copy the data to a new array. Instead you could do:

```
ireca = [reca[i] for i in [1,3,5,7]]
```

since taking only one entry of the recarray keeps the reference. You can check when a new array has been created using the `flags` parameter:

- `print(reca[0].flags)` shows `OWNDATA : False`
- `print(reca[[0,1]].flags)` shows `OWNDATA : True`

Comment: So it means that fancy indexing should be avoid in this case and the keyword 'in' is not supposed to be used for checking if a copy is made or not? Then what is the way to create a indexing view of reca rather than a simple list? I still need to call ireca['n1'] frequently afterward.

Comment: @guofeng in this approach each item in the list is a view of one part of your recarray... such that no copy is made

Comment: @guofeng did this answer fit to your needs? IF yes I just wanted to remind you can accept the answer...

Answer (score 0):

You first assigned to `ireca` the following components:

```
>>> ireca = reca[[1,3,5,7]]
>>> ireca 
rec.array([('b', 1), ('d', 3), ('f', 5), ('e', 7)], 
      dtype=[('n1', 'S8'), ('n2', '<i8')])
```

Then you assign to the first component in `'n2'` instead of `1`, `7` and then you want to see whether it is still in the parent array `reca` or not and since the second component has changed then it is no longer in `reca` so you get `False` result.

```
>>> ireca[0]['n2']=7
>>> ireca[0]
('b', 7)
>>> ireca
rec.array([('b', 7), ('d', 3), ('f', 5), ('e', 7)], 
      dtype=[('n1', 'S8'), ('n2', '<i8')])

>>> print ireca[0] in reca
False
```

Comment: It is interesting that if you replace my 4th line whit reca['n1'] = ['a']*10, you will get True.